# What is wrong with the following code which calculates a sorted array

Tags: c++, sorting

Why doesn't it return any value?
Why doesn't it give me the sorted number list back?
I am inputting a string numbers,and what an output of sorted number but again in string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class SequenceOfNumbers {
public:
    vector<string> rearrange(vector<string> sequence) {
        int i;
        int size = sizeof(sequence);
        vector<int> s1;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            s1[i] = stoi(sequence[i]);
        }
        sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sequence[i] = to_string(s1[i]);
        }
        return sequence;
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't know about the rest, but I think `int size=sizeof(sequence);` should be `int size=sequence.size();`? Or better `std::size_t size=...`

Comment: Just `std::sort( sequence.begin(), sequence.end() ) ;` is required. Don't unnecessarily complicate stuffs

Comment: @P0W: That gives a different sort order, lexicographical rather than arithmetic; 10 would come before 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
int size=sizeof(sequence);
```

You probably meant

```
int size=sequence.size();
```

which actually returns the number of elements in the std::vector container.

```
vector <int> s1;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    s1[i]=stoi(sequence[i]);
}
```

Here the problem is that the vector s1 is initialized as empty, so that you cannot change the i-th value (because it does not exist). Give the std::vector directly the correct size.

```
vector <int> s1(size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    s1[i]=stoi(sequence[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one problem:

```
int size = sizeof(sequence);
```

That gives you the size of the `vector<int>` class; not the number of elements in this vector object. You want:

```
size_t size = sequence.size();
```

Here's another problem:

```
s1[i]=stoi(sequence[i]);
```

`s1` is empty, so `s1[i]` is not valid. Instead, you must either:

- initialise the vector with the correct size, `vector<int> s1(size);`, or
- use `push_back` to grow the vector, `s1.push_back(stoi(sequence(i));`

If you're using `push_back`, you might like to do `s1.reserve(size)` first to avoid unnecessary memory allocations.

Answer (score 0):

One elegant solution would be:

```
vector<string> rearrange(const vector<string>& sequence)
{
    vector<string> result = sequence;
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(), [](string& lhs, string& rhs)
    {
        return (std::stoi(lhs) < std::stoi(rhs));
    });

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, this solution relies on std::sort. The two first parameters are the begin and end iterators of the vector. This third parameter must be a comparator used to determine the sort order (ascending or descending). Here I used a lambda function, but it could be a functor.

```
return (std::stoi(lhs) < std::stoi(rhs));
```

Here you compare the left hand-side operand (aka lhs) with the right hand-side operand (aka rhs).

Instead of a lambda expression, you could have used a functor, which is basically a class that implements:

```
bool operator()(const string& lhs, const string& rhs).
```

Depending on how big your vector is going to be, you might want to avoid copying the input vector and instead directly sort this vector in-place (remove the const-ness of 'sequence' and apply std::sort to it).